# Join or concatenate two lists in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I'm trying to join the lists `'(1 2 3)` and `'(4 5 6)` so that they become `'(1 2 3 4 5 6)`. In Clojure for example, this function is called `concat`.

I tried searching for the answer on the internet but could only find people trying to implement more advanced merge strategies for the lists.

Comment: Are you supposed to write your own (For a class) or just need to know the appropriate standard function?

Comment: There is a nice page showing similar operations in 4 lisps in [the hyperpoligot](https://hyperpolyglot.org/lisp#lists), like a rosetta stone for lisps :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In scheme this function is called `append`.